# Make: How to get prerequisite N

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's say I have a rule like this.

`cmd` is badly written, so I actually can't switch the order of the flags. `-f` **must** go before `-d`.

```
out: foo.txt mydir fizz.txt
    cmd -f fizz.txt -d mydir foo.txt
```

Is it possible to get the Nth prerequisite so that I can rewrite my rule something like this (pseudocode)?

```
out: foo.txt mydir fizz.txt
    cmd -f $^[2] -d $^[1] $<
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the Nth prerequisite

You can get the Nth word from a list with `$(word N,list)`, which should do the trick (untested):

```
out: foo.txt mydir fizz.txt
    cmd -f $(word 3,$^) -d $(word 2,$^) $<
```

Note that indexing words starts from 1, not 0. For details see
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions